# Python Beautiful Soup - find value based on text in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having a problem finding a value in a soup based on text.  Here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

html='http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aapl+Key+Statistics'
r = requests.get(html)
soup = bs(r.text)
findit=soup.find("td", text=re.compile('Market Cap'))
```

This returns [], yet there absolutely is text in a 'td' tag with 'Market Cap'.
When I use

```
soup.find_all("td")
```

I get a result set which includes:

```
<td class="yfnc_tablehead1" width="74%">Market Cap (intraday)<font size="-1"><sup>5</sup></font>:</td>
```

Comment: If you want the `text` use and iterator with `findall` and `get_text` within the iteration

Comment: What are you actually trying to extract?

Comment: Can you show me an example?  I actually don't need findAll, can just do find.  Same problem, it returns []

Comment: @Padraic, not trying to extract anything.  Just trying to locate the 'text'.

Comment: You also might find theses useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541017/web-scraping-code-to-extract-stock-price/35541497#35541497 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438381/how-to-import-a-table-with-headings-to-a-data-frame-using-pandas-module/35441264#35441264

Comment: @clg4, yes but I imagine there must be a reason why, are you simply checking for existence as some boolean test of going to be pulling a value based on where it is?

Comment: Thanks Padraic, question answered by @alecxe.  Just needed to find.  You are right, was a boolean test...

Comment: There is an yahoo finance  api  that you can use which you may find is a better option if you are doing a lot of parsing

Comment: If you want more flexibility you could also use lxml, http://pastebin.com/KWKGzUQC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The problem is that this particular tag has other child elements and the `.string` value, which is checked when you apply the text argument, is `None` (bs4 has it documented [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)).

**Solutions/Workarounds:**

Don't specify the tag name here at all, find the text node and go up to the parent:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile('Market Cap')).parent.get_text()
```

Or, you can use [`find_parent()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) if `td` is not the direct parent of the text node:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile('Market Cap')).find_parent("td").get_text()
```

You can also use a ["search function"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to search for the `td` tags and see if the direct text child nodes has the `Market Cap` text:

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag and
                      tag.name == "td" and
                      tag.find(text=re.compile('Market Cap'), recursive=False))
```

---

Or, if you are looking to find the following number `5`:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile('Market Cap')).next_sibling.get_text()
```

Comment: this does not work for me.  I show the soup, I can findAll 'td'.  I can see 'Market Cap' in one of the 'td'.  Yet when I do your first command above.  Nothing...

Comment: @clg4 okay, you might not be using the latest bs4 version, updated (replaced `string` with `text`). Works for me.

Comment: worked with text!  Why wouldn't I be able to soup.find in a specific tag like 'td'?  Or better, how would I if my above code is not correct?

Comment: @clg4 I suspect the problem is that this particular tag has other child elements and the `.string` value, which is checked when you apply the `text` argument search, is `None` (bs4 has it documented [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)).

Comment: I read that too.  The only child of the particular tag is 'font'.  Any idea a way to find text in the 'td' tag if it has a child tag?

Comment: @clg4 yeah, this was the first option: `soup.find(text=re.compile('Market Cap')).parent` - basically find the text node and then go up to the parent.

Comment: would not work if there was a 'Market Cap' in a tag different than 'td'.  I want to find all 'td', THEN see if a 'Market Cap' exists under it...

Comment: @clg4 well, `.parent` does not make assumptions about what the tag name of the parent is.

Comment: awesome, what if I wanted the NEXT sibling of the parent?

Comment: @clg4 sure, the result of the `find()` is a `Tag` instances which refers to the desired `td` element, you can call `.next_sibling` or `.next_element` or `.find_next_sibling` on it. BeautifulSoup API is quite rich and powerful.

Comment: `soup.find(text=re.compile('Market Cap')).find_parent().next_sibling()` ;) thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use regex with tag. It just won't work. Don't know if it's a bug of specification. I just search after all, and then get the parent back in a list comprehension cause "td" "regex" would give you the td tag.

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

html='http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aapl+Key+Statistics'
r = requests.get(html)
soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")

findit=soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Market Cap'))
findit=[x.parent for x in findit if x.parent.name == "td"]
print(findit)
```

**Output**

```
[<td class="yfnc_tablehead1" width="74%">Market Cap (intraday)<font size="-1"><sup>5</sup></font>:</td>]
```

Comment: Can I do this without regex?  I could not get it to work.

Comment: @clg4 You mean with out `.*`. Just saw that you want the td. tag so I know just return the x.parent instead of x. And removed the `.*`

Comment: The `.*` is not needed regardless

Comment: @PadraicCunningham already removed it. 20 seconds before your comment ;-) But thanks again!

Comment: You can also remove the parens around the if ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is just a terrible thing to integrate into parsing code and in my humble opinion should be avoided whenever possible.

Personally, I don't like BeautifulSoup due to its lack of XPath support. What you're trying to do is the sort of thing that XPath is ideally suited for. If I were doing what you're doing, I would use lxml for parsing rather than BeautifulSoup's built in parsing and/or regex. It's really quite elegant and extremely fast:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

source = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aapl+Key+Statistics').content
parsed = etree.HTML(source)
tds_w_market_cap = parsed.xpath('//td[contains(., "Market Cap")]')
```

FYI the above returns an lxml object rather than the text of the page source. In lxml you don't really work with the source directly, per se. If you need to return a list of the actual source for some reason, you would add something like:

```
print [etree.tostring(i) for i in tds_w_market_cap]
```

If you absolutely have to use BeautifulSoup for this task, then I'd use a list comprehension:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

source = requests.get('http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=aapl+Key+Statistics').content
parsed = bs(source, 'lxml')
tds_w_market_cap = [i for i in parsed.find_all('td') if 'Market Cap' in i.get_text()]
```